# How can catch log NModbus?

Tags: c#, logging, modbus

```
ModbusFactory modbus = new ModbusFactory();
TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 5000);
var master = modbus.CreateMaster(tcpClient);
var data = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 0, 2);
```

This is my NModbus code. In this case, I expect to get the result data of only response ReadHoldingRegisters(). However, I want to get not only response data but also the request byte array.

[image: ModbusSlave communication log]

The above picture is the ModbusSlave program's communication log. That shows RX/TX with a timestamp. How can I get like this RX/TX log in my C# NModbus code?

There are no available logging methods in a document of NModbus GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class GetLogMessage : ModbusLogger
    {
        public List<string> _message { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public GetLogMessage(LoggingLevel minimumLoggingLevel) : base(minimumLoggingLevel)
        {
        }

        protected override void LogCore(LoggingLevel level, string message)
        {
            _message.Add(message);
            if (level == LoggingLevel.Trace) _message.Add(message);

            Trace.WriteLine($"[{level}]".PadRight(4) + message);
        }
    }
```

I found how can get a trace log.
First, we create a new class that inherits ModbusLogger. Then create LogCore and Constructure.

Now we can get RX/TX data in _message.

```
        GetLogMessage logger = new GetLogMessage(LoggingLevel.Trace);
        ModbusFactory modbus = new ModbusFactory(null,true, logger);

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 5000);
        
        IModbusMaster master = modbus.CreateMaster(client);
        ushort[] res = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(0,0,2);

        var getlog = logger._message;
        Console.WriteLine(getlog[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(getlog[5]);
```

**Results**

[image: GetResults]